# How do I make the QueryParser in Lucene handle numeric ranges?

Tags: java, lucene

```
new QueryParser(.... ).parse (somequery);
```

it works only for string indexed fields.
Say i have a field called count where count is a integer field (while indexing the field I considered the data type)

```
new QueryParser(....).parse("count:[1 TO 10]");
```

The above one is not works. Instead If i used **"NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange"** which is working. But, i need the above one only...

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue and solved it, so here I share my solution:

To create a custom query parser that will parse the following query "INTFIELD_NAME:1203" or "INTFIELD_NAME:[1 TO 10]" and handle the field INTFIELD_NAME as an Intfield,
I overrided newTermQuery with the following:

```
public class CustomQueryParser extends QueryParser {

public CustomQueryParser(String f, Analyzer a) {
    super(f, a);
}

protected Query newRangeQuery(String field, String part1, String part2, boolean startInclusive,
    boolean endInclusive) {

    if (INTFIELD_NAME.equals(field)) {
    return NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange(field, Integer.parseInt(part1), Integer.parseInt(part2),
        startInclusive, endInclusive);
    }
    return (TermRangeQuery) super.newRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, startInclusive, endInclusive);
}


protected Query newTermQuery(Term term) {
    if (INTFIELD_NAME.equals(term.field())) {

    BytesRefBuilder byteRefBuilder = new BytesRefBuilder();
    NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(Integer.parseInt(term.text()), 0, byteRefBuilder);
    TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term(term.field(), byteRefBuilder.get()));

    return tq;
    } 
    return super.newTermQuery(term);

}
}
```

I took the code quoted in that thread from http://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=java-user@lucene.apache.org&q=subject:%22Re%3A+How+do+you+properly+use+NumericField%22&o=newest&f=1 and made 3 modifications :

- rewrote newRangeQuery a little more nicely
- replaced in newTermQuery method
  `NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(Integer.parseInt(term.text()),NumericUtils.PRECISION_STEP_DEFAULT)));`

  by `NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(Integer.parseInt(term.text()), 0, byteRefBuilder);`

when I used this method for the first time in a filter on the same numeric field, I put 0 as I found it as a default value in a lucene class and it just worked.

- replaced on newTermQuery

  `TermQuery tq =  new TermQuery(new Term(field,`

by `TermQuery tq =  new TermQuery(new Term(term.field(),`

using "field" is wrong, because if your query has several clauses (FIELD:text OR INTFIELD:100), it is taking the first or previous clause field.

Comment: I know it's been a while since you answered this, but I'm still having issues even after overriding the newTermQuery method. I still get the ```specified query 'longField:bytes' contains a string based sub query which targets numeric encoded field(s)```.

Comment: sorry, haven't used lucene since then, won't be able to help, please raise a new issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to inherit from `QueryParser` and override `GetRangeQuery(string field, ...)`. If `field` is one of your numeric field names, return an instance of `NumericRangeQuery`, otherwise return `base.GetRangeQuery(...)`.

There is an example of such an implementation in this thread: http://www.mail-archive.com/java-user@lucene.apache.org/msg29062.html

Comment: It is not working! Seems like, getRangeQuery is not overridden.

Comment: Worked for me, though this question is over three years old and regrettably I don't remember any specifics anymore...

Comment: That's okey, I have managed to solve my problem using booleanquery. But this method is not working for me in Lucene4.

Answer (score 1):

QueryParser won't create a NumericRangeQuery as it has no way to know whether a field was indexed with NumericField. Just extend the QueryParser to handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

In Lucene 6, the protected method [`QueryParser#getRangeQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#getRangeQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-) still exists with the argument list `(String fieldName, String low, String high, boolean startInclusive, boolean endInclusive)`, and overriding it to interpret the range as a numeric range is indeed possible, as long as that information is indexed using one of the new `Point` fields.

When indexing your field:

```
document.add(new FloatPoint("_point_count", value)); // index for efficient range based retrieval
document.add(new StoredField("count", value)); // if you need to store the value itself
```

At your custom query parser (extending `queryparser.classic.QueryParser`), override the method with something like this:

```
@Override
protected Query getRangeQuery(String field, String low, String high, boolean startInclusive, boolean endInclusive) throws ParseException
{
    if («isNumericField»(field)) // context dependent
    {
        final String pointField = "_point_" + field;
        return FloatPoint.newRangeQuery(pointField,
                Float.parseFloat(low),
                Float.parseFloat(high));
    }

    return super.getRangeQuery(field, low, high, startInclusive, endInclusive);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted Jeremies answer for C# and Lucene.Net 3.0.3.
I also needed type double instead of int.
This is my code:

```
using System.Globalization;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.QueryParsers;
using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Util;
using Version = Lucene.Net.Util.Version;

namespace SearchServer.SearchEngine
{
    internal class SearchQueryParser : QueryParser
    {
        public SearchQueryParser(Analyzer analyzer)
            : base(Version.LUCENE_30, null, analyzer)
        {
        }

        private const NumberStyles DblNumberStyles = NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;

        protected override Query NewRangeQuery(string field, string part1, string part2, bool inclusive)
        {
            if (field == "p")
            {
                double part1Dbl;
                if (!double.TryParse(part1, DblNumberStyles, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out part1Dbl))
                    throw new ParseException($"Error parsing value {part1} for field {field} as double.");
                double part2Dbl;
                if (!double.TryParse(part2, DblNumberStyles, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out part2Dbl))
                    throw new ParseException($"Error parsing value {part2} for field {field} as double.");
                return NumericRangeQuery.NewDoubleRange(field, part1Dbl, part2Dbl, inclusive, inclusive);
            }
            return base.NewRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, inclusive);
        }

        protected override Query NewTermQuery(Term term)
        {
            if (term.Field == "p")
            {
                double dblParsed;
                if (!double.TryParse(term.Text, DblNumberStyles, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out dblParsed))
                    throw new ParseException($"Error parsing value {term.Text} for field {term.Field} as double.");
                return new TermQuery(new Term(term.Field, NumericUtils.DoubleToPrefixCoded(dblParsed)));
            }
            return base.NewTermQuery(term);
        }
    }
}
```

I improved my code to also allow queries like greater than and lower than when an asterisk is passed. E.g. `p:[* TO 5]`

```
...
    double? part1Dbl = null;
    double tmpDbl;
    if (part1 != "*")
    {
        if (!double.TryParse(part1, DblNumberStyles, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tmpDbl))
            throw new ParseException($"Error parsing value {part1} for field {field} as double.");
        part1Dbl = tmpDbl;
    }
    double? part2Dbl = null;
    if (part2 != "*")
    {
        if (!double.TryParse(part2, DblNumberStyles, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out tmpDbl))
            throw new ParseException($"Error parsing value {part2} for field {field} as double.");
        part2Dbl = tmpDbl;
    }
    return NumericRangeQuery.NewDoubleRange(field, part1Dbl, part2Dbl, inclusive, inclusive);
...
```