# Can lucene search expression(Query Parser Syntax) search a NumericField filed?

Tags: search, search-engine, lucene.net, lucene

I use `NumericField` write a `Integer` in lucene Index:

```
doc.add(
    new NumericField("id",Integer.MAX_VALUE,Field.Store.YES,true)
        .setIntValue(123)
);
```

Now I have a problem,How Can I write a search expression by id filed(NumericField)?

I tried:

`id:123` and `id:intToPrefixCoded(123)`

but nothing for return

**Reference:**

- [Apache Lucene - Query Parser Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html)
- [NumericUtils](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/util/NumericUtils.html)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026185/how-do-i-make-the-queryparser-in-lucene-handle-numeric-ranges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because numeric fields' internal representation differs from their textual representation. You should either construct numeric queries manually or extend Lucene [query parser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html). All you need to do is to extend the `new*Query` (Term, Range, ...) methods and have an if/else test on the field name to know whether you should create a numeric query or a regular query.

See [Lucene wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/SearchNumericalFields) for more information.