# How to perform integer range query in apache lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I am using the apache lucene to perform fulltext search in my application. Now I have to perform a range query to search records between two integers.

I have created my index using following code

```
private void set(String fieldName, String fieldValue, Document luceneDocument,        LuceneOptions options, Float boost) {
    if (fieldName != null && fieldValue != null) {

        Field luceneField =
                new Field(fieldName,
                          fieldValue.toLowerCase(),
                          options.getStore(),
                          options.getIndex(),
                          options.getTermVector());

        luceneField.setBoost(boost);
        luceneDocument.add(luceneField);
    }
}
```

The above method creates the lucene indexes for my field name "magnitude" which possible values are positive and negative integers in between the range of -999 to 9999.
Now if I create a lucene range query like (magnitude:[10 to 345]) or (magnitude:[10 to null]). I am not getting the correct number of records.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make the QueryParser in Lucene handle numeric ranges?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026185/how-do-i-make-the-queryparser-in-lucene-handle-numeric-ranges)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an [`IntField`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/IntField.html) to let Lucene interpret the values as numeric.